# How to show bootstrap alert for 5 seconds even if page reloads at that moments?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to show an alert for 5 seconds on click of a button but the button is of type="submit" with method="post".So this works but only for few nanoseconds because after that page reloads and it doesn't count and show the remaining seconds of alert to show

Here is my alert code

```
<div class="alert alert-danger balance" id="inbalance" role="alert" >
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
<h4 class="alert-heading">Order <b>Unsuccessfull</b></h4>
 <p>Hey,Your order for car is Unsuccessful due to <b>insufficient balance </b> </p>
<hr>
</div>
```

Here is my code to show alert

```
function myAlertBottom(){
         $("#inbalance").show();
          setTimeout(function(){
            $("#inbalance").hide(); 
          }, 5000);
```

And button code

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg buy" onclick="myAlertBottom()" style="width:50%;"  th:disabled="${1 eq g2}">BUY</button>
```

Form code in HTML

```
<form action="" th:action="@{/g2form}" th:object= "${game2data}" 
  method="post">
  </form>
```

Comment: Please also show me your post request function code. I think you should use setTimeout on submit button when you want to make the request.

Comment: It's in spring boot (Java ) you want that or Form code in HTML ?

Comment: No not java. The javascript one.

Comment: I have use form in html Not javascript Do you need that form code ?

Comment: You are using a submit button. This, by default, submits the form it is in and reloads the page when it is clicked. If you don't want this behaviour don't use a submit button and submit the form yourself via JS when you are ready. Or use a submit button and prevent default behaviour with JS

Comment: You can't display something from the current page when a new page loads.  Submitting a form loads a new page.  You could 1) submitting page dialog with "ordering...", when page reloads show a new notification "order complete" (auto-close after 5 seconds).   2) show notification, then `$("form")[0].submit()` after 5 seconds... but seems clumsy.   3) ajax post instead of form post and reload the page via ajax.   In your case, I'd probably go with option 1), but it depends on what your notification states as the one provided is for when it fails

Comment: TBH: seems strange that you would always alert immediately that they don't have a balance, but post anyway... definitely sounds like you want a "hidden" ajax post there.  But it depends on what the page does on the reload.